# Difficulties running script at startup

Tags: boot, scripts, startup, cron

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with a usb cec-adapter attached to control my TV. I'm using a modified version of [this script](https://github.com/armills/cec-server/blob/master/cecserver.sh) to start a `cec-server` that accepts and sends commands.

So, the script works; whenever I run it manually after boot. When I issue `pidof cec-client`, it gives me an ID and I can send commands to the `cec-server` which work immediately. It's all great this way.

However, I just can't seem to get it to work through crontab or via the startup applications. `pidof cec-client` won't return an ID and I can't send commands.

TL;DR: Script works when I run it manually. Doesn't work via crontab. Want to run it automatically after a reboot.

EDIT:

The crontabline I use is `@reboot /home/server/Documents/cecserver.sh`

The script itself:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#
# Set up a fifo and connect cec-client to it
#
# Original By Will Cooke.  http://www.whizzy.org

CECLOG="/home/server/Documents/logs/cec.log"
CECDEV="/dev/ttyACM0"
CECFIFO="/home/server/Documents/logs/cec.fifo"
CECCLIENT="/usr/bin/cec-client -d 1 -p 1 -o Codex"

timestamp(){
 date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"
}

log(){
    echo "SERVER $(timestamp):  $1" >> $CECLOG
}

echo "SERVER $(timestamp): File loaded ($1)" >> $CECLOG

log "Starting server.  Since only one server can run at a time, stopping first."
log "Begin shutting down..."
declare -a TAILPIDS=(`ps aux | grep 'tail -f /dev/null' | egrep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`)
declare -a CATPIDS=(`ps aux | grep 'cat $CECFIFO' | egrep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`)
if [ ${#TAILPIDS[@]} -gt 0 ]
  then
    log "Found some tail processes..."
    for i in "${TAILPIDS[@]}"
      do
        log "Killing $i"
        kill $i
      done
fi

if [ ${#CATPIDS[@]} -gt 0 ]
  then
      log "Found some cat processes..."
      for i in "${CATPIDS[@]}"
        do
      log "Killing $i"
      kill $i
    done
fi

log "Asking cec-client to stop if it's running..."
killall -s 2 cec-client >> $CECLOG
log "Trying to remove FIFO..."
rm $CECFIFO >> $CECLOG
log "Done shutting down."
log "Done stopping, now starting..."
log "Setting up FIFOs..."
mkfifo $CECFIFO
log "Open pipe for writing..."
tail -f /dev/null > $CECFIFO &
log "Opening pipe for reading and start cec-client..."
(cat $CECFIFO | $CECCLIENT &) > /dev/null
log "Start up complete."

exit 0
```

Comment: Please add ([edit]!) the crontab line you use to start `cec-server`.

Comment: As the script is not too long please also add your version of the script.

Comment: What about making the script as a service and adding to `init.d` folder?

Comment: For additional logging, try adding `>> /tmp/cecserver.log 2>&1` to the cron tab. The output may be diagnostically useful. For even more logging change `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/bin/bash -x`.